# How to disable button until check box is checked in pyqt?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt4

I am creating an app and I need to disable a button until the user agrees to the terms. I looked online, but couldn't find anything. Any help would be great.

EDIT: I am using pyqt4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the strategy of signal/slots in Qt. When the checkbox send the checked signal you catch it with the slot defined in your button. Of course you should connect both widgets. For example:

```
connect(checkbox, SIGNAL(stateChanged(int)), button, SLOT(buttonStateChanged(int)));
```

This signals and slots maybe don't exists, and you have to create them. It is just the main idea.

I think that is a right way.

[Here](http://zetcode.com/gui/pyqt4/eventsandsignals/) are some examples of connections in python, using signal/slots. And [here is](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/794758/How-Do-I-Connect-My-Check-Box-To-Button-In-Pyqt) (maybe) what you need.

Comment: Hello again, sorry for this, but the second link you gave me is actually one of my questions, that is actually the problem i am having. I thought i'd post this question to get a new perspective.